# how to open swf file in stand alone flash player from getURL() action?

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs4

I would like to open a separate swf file from with in flash, but by default, it opens the swf in a browser. I would like this file to open in a stand alone player not in the browser. How can I achive this? Right now I'm using the getURL() action. Is there a separate function for opening a file at a specified filepath?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to open in a new Flash Player my educated guess would be: not possible

If however you wish it to open in the same window that's possible, but I'm guessing that's not what you want.